# JSON path doesn't match

Tags: rest, api, rest-assured

I tried to validate google place search api lat value from body .But i am getting JSON path doesn't match exception.

Here i shared the json format screenshot and code.Please explain where i am doing mistake .

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com";
given().
        param("input","Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia").
        param("inputtype","textquery").
        param("fields","photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry").
        param("key","<MYAPIKey>").
        when().
        get("/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json").
        then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().
        body("candidates[0].geometry.location.lat",equalTo("-33.8599358"));
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.

JSON path candidates[0].geometry.location.lat doesn't match.

Expected: -33.8599358

Actual: null

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:471)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:636)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.content(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:265)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$content$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:248)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:268)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure so I add it as a comment. You try to compare `double` to `String`. Change your `equalTo()` method argument to `double`

Comment: @Fenio Thanks for comment .I found the solution and posted my answer too.Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

i just replaced param value into

**param("input","Museum of Contemporary Art Australia")**

instead of

**param("input","Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia")**.

Working fine.